# The information system of the institution

Tags: java, beginner, collections

I've made a small project from my institute. I've got 5 classes, in 4 of the classes (`Teachers`, `Students`, `Group`, `Subject`). I've got a constructor and get&set methods. In the main class I've got an all functional realization. How can I make this code better and easier to use?

```
package com.company;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    static Main main = new Main();
    public static List<Teachers> tch = new ArrayList<Teachers>();
    public static List<Students> std = new ArrayList<Students>();
    public static List<Group> grp = new ArrayList<Group>();
    public static List<Subject> sbj = new ArrayList<Subject>();

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void io(String input){
        String surname, name, address, subjname, gradeBook;
        if(input.equals("addtch")) {
            do {
                System.out.println("Enter teacher surname: ");
                surname = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter teacher name: ");
                name = sc.nextLine();
                tch.add(new Teachers(surname, name));
                System.out.println("Add more teachers? y/n");
            } while (sc.nextLine().startsWith("y"));
        }

        if (input.equals("addstd")){ do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Enter student surname: ");
                surname = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter student name: ");
                name = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter student adress: ");
                address = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter student gradebook: ");
                gradeBook = sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter student course: ");
                int course = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter student phone number: ");
                long phoneNumb = sc.nextLong();
                std.add(new Students(surname, name, course, gradeBook, address, phoneNumb));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Wrong input");
                sc.reset();
            }
            } while (sc.nextLine().startsWith("y"));
        }

        if (input.equals("addgrp")){ do { try {
            surname = null;
            name = null;
            subjname = null;
            System.out.println("Enter group number: ");
            int groupnmb = sc.nextInt();
            grp.add(new Group(surname, name, subjname, groupnmb));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong input");
            sc.reset();
        }
        } while(sc.nextLine().startsWith("y"));
        }

        if(input.equals(("addsbj"))){ do {
            System.out.println("Enter name of subject: ");
            subjname = sc.nextLine();
            surname = null;
            name = null;
            sbj.add(new Subject(surname, name, subjname));
            System.out.println("Input again?: y/n");
        } while(sc.nextLine().startsWith("y"));
        }
    }

    public static void edit(String input) {
        Iterator<Teachers> teacherIT = tch.iterator();
        Iterator<Students> studentIT = std.iterator();
        Iterator<Group> groupIT = grp.iterator();
        Teachers teacher = teacherIT.next();
        Students student = studentIT.next();
        Group group = groupIT.next();
        String surnameToFound, newSurname, newName, newAddress, newGradeBook, groupToFound;
        long newPhoneNumb;
        int newCourse, newGroupNumb;
        if (input.equals("edittch")) {
            System.out.println("Enter teacher surname to found: ");
            surnameToFound = sc.nextLine();
            while (teacherIT.hasNext()) {
                teacher = teacherIT.next();
                if(teacher.getSurname().equals(surnameToFound)) {
                    System.out.println("Enter new teacher surname: ");
                    newSurname = sc.nextLine();
                    teacher.setSurname(newSurname);
                }
            }
        }

        if (input.equals("editstd")){
            System.out.println("Enter student surname to found: ");
            surnameToFound = sc.nextLine();
            while (studentIT.hasNext()) {
                student = studentIT.next();
                if(student.getSurname().equals(surnameToFound)) {
                    System.out.println("Enter new student surname: ");
                    newSurname = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter new student name: ");
                    newName = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter new student address: ");
                    newAddress = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter new student gradebook: ");
                    newGradeBook = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter new student course: ");
                    newCourse = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter new student phone numb: ");
                    newPhoneNumb = sc.nextLong();
                    student.setSurname(newSurname);
                    student.setName(newName);
                    student.setAddress(newAddress);
                    student.setGradeBook(newGradeBook);
                    student.setCourse(newCourse);
                    student.setPhoneNumb(newPhoneNumb);
                }
            }
        }

        if (input.equals("editgrp")){
            System.out.println("Enter group to found: ");
            groupToFound = sc.nextLine();
            while (groupIT.hasNext()){
                group = groupIT.next();
                String strInt = Integer.toString(group.getGroupNumb());
                if(groupToFound.equals(strInt)){
                    System.out.println("Enter new group numb: ");
                    newGroupNumb = sc.nextInt();
                    group.setGroupNumb(newGroupNumb);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void del(String input){
        Iterator<Teachers> teacherIT = tch.iterator();
        Iterator<Students> studentIT = std.iterator();
        Iterator<Group> groupIT = grp.iterator();
        Teachers teacher = teacherIT.next();
        Students student = studentIT.next();
        Group group = groupIT.next();

        if (input.equals("deltch")) {
            System.out.println("Enter teacher surname to delete: ");
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            while (teacherIT.hasNext()) {
                teacher = teacherIT.next();
                if (str.equals(teacher.getSurname())) {
                    teacherIT.remove();
                }
            }
        }


        if (input.equals("delstd")){
            System.out.println("Enter student surname to delete: ");
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            while (studentIT.hasNext()){
                student = studentIT.next();
                if (str.equals(student.getSurname())){
                    studentIT.remove();
                }
            }
        }

        if (input.equals("delgrp")){
            System.out.println("Enter group number to delete: ");
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            while (groupIT.hasNext()){
                group = groupIT.next();
                String strLong = Long.toString(group.getGroupNumb());
                if (str.equals(strLong)){
                    groupIT.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void control(String input){
        Iterator<Group> groupIT = grp.iterator();
        Iterator<Subject> subjectIT = sbj.iterator();
        Subject subject = subjectIT.next();
        String groupToFound, newSubj, subjToRemove, teacherSurname, teacherName, subjToFound, studentSurname, studentName;

        if (input.equals("sbjtogrp")) {
            System.out.println("Enter group to found: ");
            groupToFound = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter subject name: ");
            newSubj = sc.nextLine();
            while (groupIT.hasNext()){
                Group group = groupIT.next();
                String strInt = Integer.toString(group.getGroupNumb());
                if (groupToFound.equals(strInt) && newSubj.equals(subject.getSubjName())) {
                    group.setSubjName(newSubj);
                }
            }
        }

        if(input.equals("sbjtogrpRemove")){
            System.out.println("Enter group to found: ");
            groupToFound = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter subject te remove from group: ");
            subjToRemove = sc.nextLine();
            while (groupIT.hasNext()){
                Group group = groupIT.next();
                String strInt = Integer.toString(group.getGroupNumb());
                if (groupToFound.equals(strInt) && subjToRemove.equals(subject.getSubjName())){
                    group.setSubjName(null);
                }
            }
        }
        //4.3.  Можливість додавання викладача даного предмета вивчення
        if(input.equals("tchtosbj")){
            System.out.println("Enter subject name: ");
            subjToFound = sc.nextLine();
            while (groupIT.hasNext()){
                Group group = groupIT.next();
                if(subjToFound.equals(subject.getSubjName())){
                    System.out.println("Enter teacher surname: ");
                    teacherSurname = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter teacher name: ");
                    teacherName = sc.nextLine();
                    group.setSurname(teacherSurname);
                    group.setName(teacherName);
                }
            }
        }

        //4.4.  Можливість заміни викладача даного предмета вивчення
        if(input.equals("tchtosbjEdit")){
            System.out.println("Enter subject name: ");
            subjToFound = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter teacher surname: ");
            teacherSurname = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter teacher name: ");
            teacherName = sc.nextLine();
            while (groupIT.hasNext()){
                Group group = groupIT.next();
                if (subjToFound.equals(subject.getSubjName()) || teacherSurname.equals(group.getSurname()) || teacherName.equals(group.getName())){
                    group.setSurname(null);
                    group.setName(null);
                }
            }
        }

        if(input.equals("stdtogrp")){
            System.out.println("Enter group to found: ");
            groupToFound = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter student surname: ");
            studentSurname = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter student name: ");
            studentName = sc.nextLine();
            while (groupIT.hasNext()){
                Group group = groupIT.next();
                String strInt = Integer.toString(group.getGroupNumb());
                if (groupToFound.equals(strInt)) {
                    group.setStudList(studentSurname, studentName);
                }
            }
        }

        if(input.equals("stdtogrpRemove")){
            System.out.println("Enter group to found: ");
            groupToFound = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter student surname to remove: ");
            studentSurname = sc.nextLine();
            while (groupIT.hasNext()){
                Group group = groupIT.next();
                String strInt = Integer.toString(group.getGroupNumb());
                if (groupToFound.equals(strInt) || studentSurname.equals(group.getStudList())) {
                    group.setStudList(null, null);
                }
            }
        }

        if (input.equals("findstdfromgrp")){
            System.out.println("Enter group to found: ");
            groupToFound = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter student surname to remove: ");
            studentSurname = sc.nextLine();
            while (groupIT.hasNext()){
                Group group = groupIT.next();
                String strInt = Integer.toString(group.getGroupNumb());
                if (groupToFound.equals(strInt) || studentSurname.equals(group.getStudList())) {
                    System.out.println("Student exist in list");
                }
            }
        }

        if (input.equals("findstdfromsbj")){

        }

        if (input.equals("findstdfromtch")){

        }

    }

    public static void search(String input){
        Iterator<Teachers> teacherIT = tch.iterator();
        Iterator<Students> studentIT = std.iterator();
        if (input.equals("findtch")) {
            System.out.println("Enter surname teacher to find in list");
            String find = sc.nextLine();
            while (teacherIT.hasNext()) {
                Teachers teacher = teacherIT.next();
                if (find.equals(teacher.getSurname())) {
                    System.out.println("Teacher exist in list");
                }
            }
        }

        if (input.equals("findstd")){
            System.out.println("Enter Student surname: ");
            String surname = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Student name");
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            while (studentIT.hasNext()) {
                Students student = studentIT.next();
                if (surname.equals(student.getSurname()) && name.equals(student.getName())) {
                    System.out.println("Student exist in list");
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void elementOut(String input){
        Iterator<Teachers> teacherIT = tch.iterator();
        Iterator<Students> studentIT = std.iterator();
        Iterator<Group> groupIT = grp.iterator();
        String elementOut;
        if (input.equals("tchout")){
            System.out.println("Enter teacher surname: ");
            elementOut = sc.nextLine();
            while (teacherIT.hasNext()) {
                Teachers teacher = teacherIT.next();
                if (elementOut.equals(teacher.getSurname())){
                    System.out.println(teacher.toString());
                }
            }
        }

        if(input.equals("stdout")){
            System.out.println("Enter student name: ");
            elementOut = sc.nextLine();
            while (studentIT.hasNext()) {
                Students student = studentIT.next();
                if (elementOut.equals(student.getSurname())){
                    System.out.println(student.toString());
                }
            }
        }

        if(input.equals("grpout")){
            System.out.println("Enter group number");
            elementOut = sc.nextLine();
            while (groupIT.hasNext()) {
                Group group = groupIT.next();
                String strInt = Integer.toString(group.getGroupNumb());
                if (elementOut.equals(strInt)){
                    System.out.println(group.toString());
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public static void out(String input){
        if (input.equals("addtch") || input.equals("delnew") || input.equals("edittch") || input.equals("showtch"))
        for(Teachers t : tch) {
            System.out.println(t.toString());
        }

        if (input.equals("addstd") || input.equals("delstd") || input.equals("editstd") || input.equals("showstd"))
            for(Students s : std) {
                System.out.println(s.toString());
            }

        if (input.equals("addgrp") || input.equals("delgrp") || input.equals("editgrp") || input.equals("showgrp"))
            for(Group g : grp) {
                System.out.println(g.grpOut());
            }
        if (input.equals("sbjtogrp") || input.equals("sbjtogrpRemove") || input.equals("tchtosbj") || input.equals("tchtosbjEdit")){
            for (Group groupL : grp){
                System.out.println(groupL.toString());
            }
        }

        if (input.equals("stdtogrp") || input.equals("stdtogrpRemove")){
            for (Group groupL : grp){
                System.out.println(groupL.getStudListOut());
            }
        }
        if (input.equals("findstdfromgrp")){}

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean flag;
        System.out.println("Enter 'help'");
        for (;;) {
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            flag = false;
            if (str.equals("help")){
                System.out.println("Add/Remove/Edit/Find/Out(only 1)/show(all list) teacher - addtch/deltch/edittch/findtch/tchout/showtch \n" +
                        "Add/Remove/Edit/Find/Out(only 1)/show(all list)/FindStudentFromGroup student - addstd/delstd/editstd/findstd/stdout/showstd/findstdfromgrp \n" +
                        "Add/Remove/Edit/show(all list) group - addgrp/delgrp/editgrp/grpout/showgrp \n" +
                        "AddSubjectToGroup/RemoveSubjectFromGroup/AddTeacherToSubject/EditTeacherFromSubject/AddStudentToGroup/RemoveStudentFromGroup/ - sbjtogrp/sbjtogrpRemove/tchtosbj/tchtosbjEdit/stdtogrp/stdtogrpRemove");
                flag=true;
            }

            if(str.equals("addtch") || str.equals("addstd") || str.equals("addgrp") || str.equals("addsbj")){
                main.io(str);
                main.out(str);
                flag=true;
            }
            if (str.equals("deltch") || str.equals("delstd") || str.equals("delgrp")){
                main.del(str);
                main.out(str);
                flag=true;
            }
            if (str.equals("edittch") || str.equals("editstd") || str.equals("editgrp")){
                main.edit(str);
                main.out(str);
                flag=true;
            }
            if (str.equals("findtch") | str.equals("findstd")){
                main.search(str);
                flag=true;
            }
            if (str.equals("tchout") || str.equals("stdout") || str.equals("grpout")){
                main.elementOut(str);
                flag=true;
            }
            if (str.equals("showtch") || str.equals("showstd") || str.equals("showgrp")){
                main.out(str);
                flag=true;
            }
            if (str.equals("sbjtogrp") || str.equals("sbjtogrpRemove") || str.equals("tchtosbj") || str.equals("tchtosbjEdit") || str.equals("stdtogrp") || str.equals("stdtogrpRemove") || str.equals("findstdfromgrp")){
                main.control(str);
                main.out(str);
                flag=true;
            }
            if (str.equals("exit")){
                break;
            }
            if (!flag)
                System.out.println("There is no such command: "+str);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Variable Names**

There is no good reason to abbreviate variable and method names, but it does make your code a lot harder to read.

- `tch` should be `teachers`, `std` should be `students`, etc.
- `subjname` should be `subjectName`.
- `sc` should be `scanner`.
- `io` should probably be named something like `add` (it only adds, it doesn't delete, etc, and it definitely doesn't just perform input/output).

The same is also true for input strings. For example, nobody will be able to remember `addtch`.

**Code length**

Your main class is way too big. A first step to fixing this would be to extract duplicate code. For example, you have this very often:

```
System.out.println("Some message");
someVar = sc.nextLine();
```

If you extract it to a method:

```
private static String getInput(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
        return sc.nextLine();
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
someVar = getInput("Some message");
```

Yes, it only saves one line, but you really do have it in a lot of places, so it's worth it.

**Indentation**

Proper indentation is important for readability. For example this code:

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Wrong input");
        sc.reset();
    }
    } while(sc.nextLine().startsWith("y"));
    }
```

It's really hard to see where what ends. You can fix this very easily with any IDE.

**Duplicate `if`s**

It is odd that you ask in your main method `if(str.equals("addtch") || str.equals("addstd") || str.equals("addgrp") || str.equals("addsbj"))`, and then call `main.io(str)`, where you again ask `if(input.equals("addtch"))`, etc.

Just ask once, and create separate methods for `addTeacher`, etc.

**Misc**

- Your many `if` with the `flag` to see if there was a valid input could easily be written as a switch.
- `static Main main = new Main();` isn't needed at all. As all your methods are static, you can just to `Main.io()`, or just `io()`.
- define variables in as small a scope as possible. Eg `address` is only needed in one of the `if`s, `teacherIT` is also only used in a single `if`, but defined at function level, etc.
- instead of `for (;;)` it is customary to use `while(true)`.